# How to delete an item from a Set?

Tags: java, collections

```
final Set<Expression> exps = meng.getExps();
Iterator<Expression> iterator = exps.iterator();
final Expression displayedExp = exps.iterator().next();
exps.remove(displayedExp);
```

This code would return the following run-time exceptions trace:

```
null
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.remove(Collections.java:1021)
```

The Set implementation of meng.getExps() is a LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Bsahtek the 10k!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, you are out of luck: The Set was wrapped with [Collections.unmodifiableCollection](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29), which does exactly this: making the collection unmodifiable. The only thing you can do is copy the content into another Set and work with this.

Comment: and is there any utility like Collection.copy to do that?

Comment: E.g. Set<Expression> set = new HashSet<Expression>(exps);

Comment: @Landei is it the default java behavior or do we have to explicitly wrap it with Collections.unmodifiableCollection. If it is by default, do you know in which version of java was this change added?

Comment: @Atri I think you got my answer wrong. The iterator function of this particular Set implementation (the code example doesn't show you which one, and it is also not clear if this implementation is modifiable itself) is using a wrapped, unmodifiable collection under the hoods, which prevents that the original set is changed via the iterator. I don't know what you want to achieve, but whether or not an iterator may change the underlying collection is totally up to the implementer.

Answer (score 4):

Your getter is explicitly returning you an `UnmodifiableCollection`, which is a wrapper of sorts around `Set`s that prevents modification.

In other words, the API is telling you "this is my collection, please look but don't touch!"

If you want to modify it, you should copy it into a new Set.  There are copying constructors for `HashSet` that are great for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your Set as '**final**', which means that it can not be modified. The error you get is normal.

If you want to change the content of the Set, remove 'final'.

Comment: this answer is wrong and should be removed.

Comment: you can add and remove elements from a final Collection (Set, List, etc). What you can't do is initialize a new Set in the same variable.

Comment: but the set itself isn't actually "final". The variable (in this case `exps`) is final. How you declare a variable has absolutely no impact on the set. That's why this is wrong and should be deleted. But this is Stack Overflow where you get punished for pointing out that something is wrong and should be deleted.